# What does the additional JavaScript mean in node document?

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

Blocking is when the execution of additional JavaScript in the Node.js process must wait until a non-JavaScript operation completes. This happens because the event loop is unable to continue running JavaScript while a blocking operation is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

It means the rest of your JavaScript code, that hasn't been excuted yet. It's blocked from being excuted, until non-JavaScript operation completes.

They explain it in the next section in the documentation: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/#comparing-code

In the first example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync('/file.md'); // blocks here until file is read
console.log(data);
moreWork(); // will run after console.log
```

The **additional JavaScript** code here is the 2 lines that are blocked by the synchronous file reading, above it. These 2 lines don't get excuted until the file reading is complete:

```
console.log(data);
moreWork(); // will run after console.log
```

Tip: when you ask a question, it's best to add sources if your question references another website. In this case: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/#blocking